# Button that changes database value in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, button

Part of Group show.html.erb looks like:

```
  <% if !@pending.empty? %>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"> <h4>Pending Approvals for Group</h4></div>
    <table class="table", style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px 1px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Email</th>
          <th>Accept/Reject</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <% @pending.each do |individual| %>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><%= individual.user.email %></td>
          <td>Accept/Reject (BUTTONS HERE)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

Instead of the Accept/Reject , I need to have two buttons that changes the value in the database column membership. Accept would put a value of "member" and Reject would put "denied". However, this change is in the GroupUser not Group, which is a joint table of Groups and Users.

In other words, the accept button would essentially do `<% individual.update(membership: "member")%>` and reject would do `<% individual.update(membership: "denied")%>`.

The button would then change to something like, Approved or Denied. I tried various options but none of them seem to work. I am not sure if/how it can be achieved with javascript or jQuery.

This is part of my attempt to create a "Join Group" request feature that allows other users to request to join a private group and gain membership.

Comment: whats the controller, action that does the updating? you have code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was a link (button) that would pass the parameters to a controller, which would make the change according to these parameters like shown below:

Group show.html.erb

```
        <td><%= link_to 'Accept', {:controller => "group",
                                   :action => "decision",
                                   :id => individual.group_id,
                                   :user_id => individual.user.id,
                                   :decision => "true"}, method: 'post', class: "btn btn-sm btn-success" %>
```

Group controller

```
  def decision
    @groupUser = GroupUser.where(group_id: params[:id], user_id: params[:user_id])
    if params[:decision] == "true"
      @groupUser.update(membership: "member")
      Homework.where(group_id: params[:id]).find_each do |hw|
        UserHomework.create(user_id: params[:user_id], homework_id: hw.id, admin: true, status: 'No attempt')
      end
    else
      @groupUser.update(membership: "denied")
    end
    redirect_to groupshow_path(:id => params[:id])
  end
```